# How to define and work with variables within a class definition that do not become class variables in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, static-variables

This is more a theoretical question than an actual problem. My program is running, I just want to get deeper insight into the Python internals.

I'm writing a Python module that implements a number of classes which are very similar between them, although they strongly differ in the values of their attributes, which are rather boring and cumbersome to set from the point of view of the user of the class. Therefore I think this is a good place to rely on inheritance, and build derived classes that take care of the instantiation of these attributes. The problem I have is that the way I have found to implement this leaves an ugly trace: unwanted class variables.

A simple example that showcases my problem is below. A parent class (that is not intended to be used to create objects, but rather to serve as an abstract class base):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

And a child class that basically is used to take care of setting the `a` attribute transparently for the users:

```
class Child(Parent):
    a = 0   # <- I'm aware that the problem is here
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.a)
```

From the point of view of the user of this module, this already works as expected:

```
instanceChild = Child()  # you can instance the class without having to worry for `a`
instanceChild.a          # returns 0 as expected
```

However this seems to me an ugly implementation as it has the side effect of having declared an unwanted  class variable:

```
instanceChild.__dict__
{'a': 0}
instanceChild.__class__.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'a': 0,
              '__init__': <function __main__.Child.__init__(self)>,
              '__doc__': None}
```

**Is there a way to define a variable within the implementation of `Child`that does not create a class variable?**

Note: I'm aware that a solution for this example would be to define `Child` as follows:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(a = 0)
```

But note that my real problem is more convoluted, there are several parametres to set and they are cumbersome and hardcoded at class definition. I really want, for the sake of maintenance, to have this information stored as separated, understandable variables. It's just that I want these variables to get forgotten by Python once the instance of the class is created and this information is already stored in the object attributes.

Comment: The user of the class should not have to look at the code in order to know what the user-level attributes are. Write proper documentation.

Comment: Which class? My idea is that the user of the module won’t use directly the Parent class at all, but one of the implemented children. This is, the user doesn’t even need to know that the ‘a’ attribute exists at all. If I could, I’d make the Parent class abstract, and these attributes hidden. But my question is about something else: how to effectively keep developing derived classes for the user.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question then, sorry.